# Cardinality of a elliptic curve over a finite field

Tags: proof-verification, finite-groups, modular-arithmetic, elliptic-curves

I want to calculate the cardinality of $E_p(\mathbb F_p)$ where $E_p$ is the elliptic curve defined by the reduction of $Y^2=X^3-17$ modulo $p$.

Somehow I don't get the right results/the results the computer tells me to be true.

If $p=2$, then I need $Y^2 \equiv X^3-1 \mod 2$. To me this seems fulfilled only for $(0,1), (1,0) \in \mathbb F_2$.
Including the point at infinity we get $\text{card } E_p(\mathbb F_p)=3$, but the computer tells me $\text{card } E_p(\mathbb F_p)=2$.

If $p=3$, then I need $Y^2 \equiv X^3-2 \mod 3$. To me this seems fulfilled only for $(0,1), (0,2), (2,0) \in \mathbb F_2$.
Including the point at infinity we get $\text{card } E_p(\mathbb F_p)=4$, but the computer tells me $\text{card } E_p(\mathbb F_p)=3$.

If $p=5$, then I need $Y^2 \equiv X^3-2 \mod 5$. To me this seems fulfilled only for $(1,2), (1,3), (2,1), (2,4), (3,0) \in \mathbb F_2$.
Including the point at infinity we get $\text{card } E_p(\mathbb F_p)=6$, this time this is the right result.

I am quite convinced that my calculations are right. Did I miss something conceptually? Would be nice, if anybody could check my calculations.

Comment: $y^2=x^3-1$ is not an elliptic curve over $\Bbb F_2$.

Comment: $y^2=x^3-1$ is not an elliptic curve over $\Bbb F_3$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown why are these no elliptic curves? (in the case of $F_3$, do you mean $x^3-2$?

Comment: @DietrichBurde: No, the difference ion not $1$ in all cases, only in the first two, the case $p=5$ is right, hence my confusion

Comment: @mathsta I mean in both cases that $y^2=x^3-17$ isn't an elliptic curve over those fields - to late to edit now!

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown: But why is that? Do we need to calculate the discrimant, i reduce the polynomial mod $2$ and calculate the discrminant $D= -16*27\neq 0$. Or do i need to show that the discrimant is not even?

Comment: @mathsta The discriminant needs to be nonzero over the finite field. In $\mathbb{F}_2$, $16=0$ so your discriminant is $0$ here and similarly for $\mathbb{F}_3$ as then $27=0$.

Comment: @MattB Thank you. Does this mean that there are no elliptic curves over $\mathbb F_2$?

Comment: On the contrary, there are tons of them; they just don't usually get written in the form $y^2=x^3+Ax+B$. For example $y^2+y=x^3-x^2$ is an elliptic curve over $\mathbb{F}_{p}$ for any $p$ different to $11$.

Comment: You could make a substitution and rewrite this as $y^2=x^3-432x+8208$ but the discriminant is now divisible by $2$ and $3$. Although it turns out that the powers of $2$ and $3$ are divisible by $12$ which actually means we will still get an elliptic curve over $\mathbb{F}_2$ so long as we make a change of variables.

Comment: If you want a massive list, check out http://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/; the ones which are elliptic curves over $\mathbb{F}_2$ are precisely those with odd conductor.

Comment: Over $\Bbb{F}_2$ the elliptic curves are (up to isomorphism + IIRC) $y^2+xy=x^3+1$, $y^2+xy=x^3+x+1$, $y^2+xy=x^3+x$, $y^2+y=x^3$, $y^2+y=x^3+1$, $y^2+y=x^3+x+1$, $y^2+y=x^3+x+1$. The problem is that the short Weierstrass form is not available in characteristics two and three, because transforming the equation to the short form requires the ability to divide by two and three, and these become division by zero in low characteristic.